# Identify Volunteers in contact summary

Tags: civivolunteer

I am testing the CiviVolunteer extension and was wondering if there is anyway to identify that a contact signed up to volunteer based on their profile? I assigned a few volunteers to an event, but I do not see that they signed up anywhere on their profile. I don't even see the event show up on their event tab. Let me know if I am missing anything or if this is a future enhancement. Thank you!

Comment: Which version of CiviVolunteer?

Answer (score 3):

For now in the contact's profile click on the activities tab and filter out the activity type = volunteer. Status available means the contact has not been assigned to a specific need. Status scheduled means they have been assigned to a specific need.

Comment: Yes, that's right. There is no volunteer tab on the contact summary at this time. Volunteer activities are *not* event registrations, but as stated above are recorded as Activities.

Answer (score 1):

Under 'CiviVolunteer' -> 'Manage Volunteers' (or similar). I couldn't confirm as none of CiviVolunteer's menus are working on the demo site. I agree a 'volunteer' tab on the contact screen would be great (I thought there was one? It wouldn't be hard to make - drop an email to info@ginkgostreet.com to find out more).

Comment: I'm not sure there is an info@ginkgostreet.com. Please make feature requests or report bugs in the CiviVolunteer project in CiviCRM's issue tracking system (https://issues.civicrm.org).